# Dynamically building a URL in QTP

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, webtest

I've been taking a quick look at QTP with one of our test team.

We've figured out some basics like recording a test, capturing text using output values, putting in check points, etc.

However, I can't figure out how to do the following...

We have a web form which a user fills in and submits. This will create an item and assign it an ID in the database. We can capture this ID.

A subsequent page then shows a list of all items, with a link available to open a specific item. This is a simple hyperlink on a web page.

How do I:

- Check that a link exists on the page with the ID assigned from the creation step?
- Click that link?

I'm sure that this must be possible, but I've been struggling grokking the tool so far, so this is a shameless cry for help to save me from having to study the docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Heaven forbid you read the docs! ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Quickly look on Web GUI recognition principles in QTP. Get to the descriptive programming part.
2. Find Help for Link object in QTP.
3. Define your target Link object using descriptive programming.
   It should be something like

   `Set objTargetLink = Browser("title:=...").Page("title:=...").Frame("title:=...").Link("id:=target_id")`
4. Use

   `boolRC = objTargetLink.Exist(0)`

   To check if your link exists.
5. Use

   `sURL = objTargetLink.GetTOProperty("url")`

   to retrieve the actual url. You may get other properties the same way.
6. Use `objTargetLink.Click` to click on the link.

PS. Functional Test Automation is something different, though.
Ask your testing team to read about automation frameworks and automation requirements.
I have some stuff on my blog.
http://automation-beyond.com/2009/06/06/qa-test-automation-requirements-usability/

Thank you,
Albert Gareev

http://automation-beyond.com/

Comment: Great answer, the only thing is I think that QTP anchors the beginning and end of properties so you may have to use `"id:=.*target_id.*"` instead of Albert's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks - we'll give this a go. The issue I think we'll have is that our testing team is looking for a tool which can be mainly point and click. This seems OK for basic stuff. But it seems we've got to drop down to code if you want to do anything trickier. Our testers aren't developers - they are pure functional testers. So I'm not sure how much mileage we'd get out of QTP. Is this a fair comment or am I doing a disservice to the tool?

Comment: A_M, test automation really needs to be treated as software development. As you have already noticed the need to "drop down to code". So you are not going to get great mileage out of any automation tool without programming skills. This may require developers to help out, or adding staff with some decent programming chops to be able to build a robust and maintainable automation suite.

Comment: Motti, didn't get you about "QTP anchors the beginning and end of properties".. If "target_id" should be exact and not regex why make a regex from it?

I've just tried a minute ago:
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebButton("name:=Google Search").Click
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebButton("name:=Google Se.*").Click
BOTH ways work.

Comment: A_M, any "point and click" ( = "record/playback") is always use-once. Creation cost is low but flexibility is near zero and maintenance cost is huge. That is why if you have major problems with scripts just throw them away and record from scratch... but don't expect good coverage anyway.
PS. Tom E, strongly agree, voted up - they really need an automation developer in the team, and they'll have to invest in framework first.

Comment: As a new 'automation developer', I concur with @Albert Gareev - QTP is all right for this purpose, I think, although I'm not the biggest fan of VBScript.